# Can you copy Swing code and see it in designer in intelliJ

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I created a new Gui form in intelliJ and copied my Swing code, i already had from eclipse to this file. But intelliJ doesn't update the form in the designer.

Is it possible in intelliJ to code youre GUI and see it in the designer?

Comment: IntelliJ's GUI designer is based on an XML file (Foo.form), so adding components manually in the Java class won't make them visible in the designer.

Comment: @BastienJansen thanks

Comment: You *might* be able to view your code in action when you [preview the form](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/previewing-forms.html), but I haven't tested that so it might not work.